# Why the variable is not available in the new and the create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to do a form submission, in which the new method initializes the variable and in the create method, the variable is supposed to save to the model. But in the create method, I am getting a nil for that variable. So I am ending up creating the variable in the create method also. Can anyone help in me understand what is going on.

Here is my code

```
class AddressesController < ApplicationController

    def new
        byebug
        @addr = Address.new
    end

    def create 

        @addr = Address.new
        byebug
        user = {}
        user[:user_id] = StudioOrder.find_by(user_id: spree_current_user.id).user_id
        @addr.update_attributes(user)
        @addr.update_attributes(getparams)
        byebug
        @addr.save

    end

    def getparams
        params.require(:address).permit(:user_id, :name, :address, :mobile, :city, :state, :pincode)
    end

end
```

Comment: An address always belongs_to a user?

Comment: Which variable is nil?

Comment: Any instance variable which has not been defined will have a value of `nil`.  So if something is nil, it's either been **set to nil** or **has not been defined**.  Bear in mind that rails starts from scratch with every request:  if you do the new action, define something, render out a form, and then submit the form, the old variable won't still be defined:  you will need to define it again each time.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly my confusion. When I defined @ addr variable in the new method, and expected that variable will be available in the create method. Only to find out that is not available. Then how do we communicate the variables between different instances, if does not seem to be too vague. Please clarify, Thanks. @MaxWilliams

Comment: @ addr variable I was talking about. Sorry for the late reply. @Pavan

Comment: Like i said **Bear in mind that rails starts from scratch with every request: if you do the new action, define something, render out a form, and then submit the form, the old variable won't still be defined: you will need to define it again each time**.  "Instances" don't communicate with each other: if you want to send info into the controller you do it with params.

Comment: Then why did I init the variable @addr in the new action? If cannot communicate that variable, I know that there will be an error if I don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `spree_current_user` `has_many :addresses` and it must exist to get to the addresses  controller you can do

```
def create 
  @addr = spree_current_user.addresses.new(get_params)  
  if @addr.save
    flash[:notice] 'save successful'
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    flash.now[:error] 'please correct errors below'
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: There is an user_id column in the address model, so why do I need to to have has_many relationship? Can you please explain?

Comment: If you don't this `spree_current_user.addresses.new(get_params)` won't work

Comment: Yes, correct. But how do I override the SpreeUser to have a relationship with my address model.

Comment: I've never used Spree, so I have no idea.  You could do `@addr = Address.new(get_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id)`

Comment: Thanks .. but it's lots more complicated than that :)

Answer (score 1):

The variable you're talking about is @addr

This is perfectly normal.  It is a variable defined for THAT INSTANCE of the AddressesController class.

When the create method executes, that's a NEW instance of the AddressesController class and has no access to the instance variables of the previous instance.

As to this line...

```
user[:user_id] = StudioOrder.find_by(user_id: spree_current_user.id).user_id
```

it could be vastly simplified to

```
user[:user_id] = spree_current_user.id
```

Anyway, a simplified version of your controller actions could be ...

```
def new
  @addr = Address.new
end

def create 
  @addr = Address.new
  @addr.assign_attributes(getparams)
  @addr.user = spree_current_user
  if @addr.save
    flash[:notice] 'save successful'
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    flash.now[:error] 'please correct errors below'
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: Actually user_id is a column in that model address, so I should be doing @ addr.user_id = spree_current_user? instead of @ addr.user. And thanks for pointing out that long line of code :)

Comment: If the association is set up, then Rails understands 'user' and 

`@addr.user = spree_current_user` is effectively the same as `@addr_user_id = spree_current_user.id`

Comment: The avantage of using `user` (instead of `user_id` is that it's more abstract... in future if your design changes so that (for example) Address belongs to User through some other model, the abstracted code still works.  The code referencing "user_id" means your controller has to know too much about how your relationships are constructed.